# Understanding "this" in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 blocks of code, one that does not work, and one that works because I assign that = this and use that in my function instead of this. Can someone help me understand why this is so. It would help to know how one should think of accessing variables in functions in objects in JavaScript, and the nature of "this", if I am saying that right (if not, please enlighten me). Thank you!

```
var add = function (x, y) {
  return x + y;
  }

var myObject = {
  value: 0,
  increment: function (inc) {
    this.value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    }
};

myObject.double2 = function () {
  // var that = this; 

  var helper = function () {
    this.value = add(this.value, this.value)
  };

  helper();
};

myObject.increment(100);
document.writeln(myObject.value); // Prints 100
myObject.double2();
document.writeln('<BR/>'); // Prints <BR/>
document.writeln(myObject.value); // Prints 100, **FAILS**
```

And the modified code:

```
var add = function (x, y) {
  return x + y;
  }

var myObject = {
  value: 0,
  increment: function (inc) {
    this.value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    }
};

myObject.double2 = function () {
  var that = this;  

  var helper = function () {
    that.value = add(that.value, that.value)
  };

  helper();
};

myObject.increment(100);
document.writeln(myObject.value); // Prints 100
myObject.double2();
document.writeln('<BR/>'); // Prints <BR/>
document.writeln(myObject.value); // Prints 200 - **NOW IT WORKS**
```

Comment: `this` refers to the local execution context. (I am 100% sure someone else can word that better then me.) Your `that` variable is a closure, that captures the value of the `this` so that you can reference it from inside the function call, whenever it happens, at some point in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one doesn't work because when each function's `this` depends on how it was called.

First you do `myObject.double2()` and so `this = myObject`. But inside `double2`, you call `helper()` by itself and there is no object you're calling it under (it's not `myObject.helper()`). So `this` defaults to the `global` object (or `window` object in a browser).

In the second example, you "capture" a reference to `myObject` (`that=this=myObject`) and so `that.value=myObject.value`.

Comment: thanks! That is a very clear description and makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think this [link](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) would greatly help you in understanding the differences of object and private members in Javascript to tackle your problem, please take a look at the **Private** section. Hope it helps!

Comment: I suppose you forgot the link

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I don't see your link though

Answer (score 1):

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) has some good reading on this. If you want this to work without assigning `this` to `that`, you can always use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Example: jsfiddle.net/5azde/

Answer (score 0):

And you can always remember this:

> When a function of an object is called, the object will be passed as this value(as the case 'add' and 'increment' function which belong to 'window' and 'myObject' separately). And if the function doesn't belong to any objects, window(or global) will be passed as this value.(as the case with function helper in your sample code).

And I'm glad to see a pure js question. No jQuery, No css, No dom selector. haha.

May it helps. :-)

Comment: and please note that, every function's this value is defined and unchangeable when the function is formed. But you can modify 'this' value with 'call' or 'apply' function.