# Keeps saying result property is not defined. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my object and I have defined all the properties and functions but it still gives me this error `result is not defined`.

Here is my code

```
var Xml = {
    to      : null,
    from    : null,
    url     : null,
    result  : null,  //<--- I defined result here

    init: function (fromaddress, toaddress, link) {
        from    = fromaddress;
        to      = toaddress;
        url     = link;

        this.requestXml();
        return this;
    },

    requestXml: function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: this.parseXml
        });
    },

    parseXml: function (xml) {
        console.log('xml: ' + $(xml));
        result = $(xml); //<--- Assigning value to result here
    },

    getResult: function () {
        console.log('Result: ' + result); // <--- Here is says result is not defined
        return result;
    }
};
```

How can I solve this problem?

**Update**

I am calling getResult() below

```
var Route = {
fromurl : null,
tourl   : null,
from    : null,
to      : null,

init: function (fromaddress, toaddress) {
    from        = fromaddress;
    to          = toaddress;
    fromurl     = 'http://demo.com/url'+fromurl;
    tourl       = 'http://demo.com/url'+tourl;

    Route.searchRoute();
},

searchRoute: function () {
    var xml = Xml.init(from, to, fromurl);
    console.log(xml.getResult()); //<---- calling getResult();
}

 };
```

Comment: This is because an AJAX request is asynchronous and I would assume that you're calling `obj.getResult()` straight after `obj.requestXml()`. At that point the AJAX request would not have completed, so `result` is undefined.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so how can I force it to wait until ajax request is completed?

Comment: Make sure to call `getResult` _after_ your assignment in `parseXml`.  You should restructure the code so that you pass in a callback to actually process your result right after you call `parseXml`, rather that squirreling it away inside the object so that you have to call a getter at some later time.  Having a "getter" like this is not the way asynchronous code was meant to be structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "undecorated" expression `result` would refer to a global variable named `result`, which you do not have.

It is not correct to assume that just because a reference to `result` is textually inside of an object that the reference refers to a property of that object.  That may be the case in other languages, but not in JavaScript.

The solution to your problem is in one of the comments to the question.  Using `this.` as a prefix works in these cases.  Try this code:

```
var x = 1;

var p = {
   x: 2,
   f: function () {alert(x); alert(this.x);}
}

p.f();
```

Here you will see 1 alerted and then 2.

*Answer to updated question*

What you have here is a classic problem.  You write

```
var xml = Xml.init(from, to, fromurl);
console.log(xml.getResult()); //<---- calling getResult();
```

The first line eventually fires of an Ajax request.  Once that request is fired off, you immediately go to your second line, where you call `xml.getResult()`.  Chances are nearly 100% that the call to `getResult` will happen **before** your Ajax call is able to fill in the value of `result`.

One approach is to pass the thing you want to *do* with the result to the `init` method.  In this case it looks like you want to log the result, so try

```
var xml = Xml.init(from, to, fromurl, function () {console.log(xml.getResult()});
```

Here we have a new fourth parameter to `Xml.init` so we have to handle that by updating the `Xml` object, like so (not tested):

```
.
.
.
init: function (fromaddress, toaddress, link, callback) {
    from    = fromaddress;
    to      = toaddress;
    url     = link;

    this.requestXml(callback);
    return this;
},

requestXml: function (callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: callback
    });
},

.
.
.
```

In other words, when you are going to make asynchronous calls, consume the results right away.  Don't save them away for later, because you never know when they are going to be "ready".

Comment: How can I resolve this problem? Any demo code would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It first alerts 1 (the global x) then 2 (the x property of the object through which the function was called).

Comment: This way it has a value of `undefined`

Comment: If you are referring to the fact that simply adding `this.` to the code in your question results in `undefined` then yes, this is true because your code is not "doing Ajax properly."  Your actual _question_, though, was why you got a reference error.  The reference error occurred because you didn't have the `this.`  The undefined issue is something extra. You might want to ask another question about why you get undefined, or update your question accordingly.  In either case, I commented on your question regarding that issue.  Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Ok I asked another question regarding this

Comment: Yes I already thought about it but how can I force it to wait until it completes the ajax call and fill in result variable then call getResult()?

Comment: By not using `getResult()` but rather doing what you want to do with the result right away, as soon as the ajax call returns.  I've updated the answer again.

Comment: I appreciate you answer and added the callback as you suggested in your answer but it still returns undefined whereas when I use `console.log($(xml))` in parseXml then it does have xml data.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `this`, but it might be easier if you use a constructor so you have access to the properties in all methods:

```
function Xml(to, from, url, result) {
  this.to      = to || null;
  this.from    = from || null;
  this.url     = url || null;
  this.result  = result || null;
  // init logic
}

Xml.prototype = {

  parseXml: function (xml) {
    console.log('xml: ' + $(xml));
    this.result = $(xml);
  },

  getResult: function () {
    console.log('Result: ' + this.result);
    return this.result;
  }

  ...

}

var xml = new Xml(to, from, url, result); // init
```

**Edit:** An object literal might not be the best option. Your case is more suited for a constructor like above, or a module pattern if you want to avoid the `this` confusion:

```
function Xml() {

  var xml = {}
    , to = null
    , from = null
    , url = null
    , result = null;

  xml.parseXml = function( xml ) {
    ...
  };

  ...

  return xml;

}

var xml = Xml();
```

Comment: It does not work in your example because you're using a literal object. Declare an empty object first like `xml = {}` and add methods with dot notation like `xml.getResult = function(){ ... }`, then to use properties that already exist just do `xml.property` instead of `this.`.

Comment: Even if I use this.result then it returns `undefined` unlike `result is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

try `XML.result`

See [Understanding "this" in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813871/understanding-this-in-javascript) for a discussion of the ins and outs of `this` and what it points to a different times.