# After parsing xml I am getting undefined as a result

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeps saying result property is not defined. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285770/keeps-saying-result-property-is-not-defined-why)

I am parsing xml and what I want is to return xml after parsing it. The problem is that in my `getResult()` function `result` has a value of `undefined`. Why and how can I make it work?

Here is my code

```
var result  = '';

var Xml = {
to      : null,
from    : null,
url     : null,

init: function (fromaddress, toaddress, link) {
    from    = fromaddress;
    to      = toaddress;
    url     = link;

    this.requestXml();
    return this;
},

requestXml: function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: this.parseXml
    });
},

parseXml: function (xml) {
    console.log('xml: ' + $(xml));
    result = $(xml);
},

getResult: function () {
    console.log('Result: ' + Xml.result); //<--- Here result has undefined value
    return result;
}
};
```

Comment: In `parseXml` if you do `console.lo($(xml))` do you have the values or is it already `undefined` there?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question?

Comment: Please post the response XML too!

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I do have the value there.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It is not duplicate. Previous question solved one of my issue but this is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved my issue

```
var Xml = function () {
var to, from, url, result,

    init = function (fromaddress, toaddress, link, callback) {
        from    = fromaddress;
        to      = toaddress;
        url     = link;

        requestXml(callback);
    },

    requestXml = function (callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: callback
        });
    },

    getResult = function () {
        return result;
    };

 return {
    init        : init,
    getResult   : getResult
 };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Xml.result is never being set. Maybe I'm missing something, but you will need to do this in parseXml in order to set its result field:

```
this.result = $(xml);
```

And in getResult your console.log call shouldn't show undefined. You can even have it return `this.result`.

Another thing, in your initializer, you should be setting each property with the "this" keyword.

Comment: You are not using 'this' anywhere to set the Xml object's fields. You're not using 'this' in the initializer, and you're not using 'this' in the requestXml function for the url field.

Comment: Xml does not itself contain a closure since it is not a function. Defining its fields (to, from, url, etc.) will not be treated as variables in its scope. You need to set them with the 'this' keyword. Such as 'this.url = link;' in the initializer and 'this.url' in the $.ajax url field.

Comment: Still the same result after adding this everywhere which you mentioned.

Comment: @Vinay: I played around with this some more and your suggestion should work perfectly. I also added a small DEMO to my post to test the code itself as a proof of concept, passing around a simple string instead of `$(xml)` and it works as expected. I think the problem is more to do with the unexpected result of encapsulating the xml data into the `$()`. I +1 your answer as you have addressed the issues in the code construction. The main issue seems to be what's going on in `parseXml` though.

Comment: The DEMO for completeness: http://jsfiddle.net/f4cLz/