# Controller as syntax issues

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller, controller

I'm trying to use the `Controller as` syntax but I can't manage to make it work.

For example, here is a working code :

View :

```
<div ng-controller="ProjectsController">
  Projects view : <br />
  {{ projectsData }}
</div>
```

Controller :

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('ProjectsController', function($scope, Projects) {
    Projects.get().then(function(result) {
      $scope.projectsData = result.data;
    });
  });
```

And here is the Projects factory :

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('Projects', function($http) {
    return {
      get: function() {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/catalog/projects');
      }
    };
  });
```

This way is working, using the normal syntax for controller and the `$scope` object inside of it.

But I can't get it to work when I'm using the `Controller as` syntax, like the following :

View :

```
<div ng-controller="ProjectsController as p">
  Projects view : <br />
  {{ p.projectsData }}
</div>
```

For the controller I tried :

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('ProjectsController', function(Projects) {
    Projects.get().then(function(result) {
      this.projectsData = result.data;
    });
  });
```

but also :

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('ProjectsController', function($scope, Projects) {
    Projects.get().then(function(result) {
      $scope.projectsData = result.data;
    });
    this.projectsData = $scope.projectsData;
  });
```

But none of it worked, I had nothing in the view for `{{ projectsData }}`.

However, when I tried to test this as the controller using `Controller as` syntax :

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('ProjectsController', function($scope, Projects) {
    Projects.get().then(function(result) {
      $scope.projectsData = result.data;
    });
    console.log($scope.projectsData);
    this.projectsData = "TEST";
  });
```

I had my "TEST" displayed in the view, and `$scope.projectsData` was `undefined`.

So how can I set my controller in order to access it properly using the `Controller as` syntax ?

Comment: `this` is not what you expect, it is the context of the function passed to `then()`. Store the `this` controller like `var self = this;` and use that instead. Or use `angular.bind` to bind the function to the controller context. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813871/understanding-this-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you need to store a reference of `this` in controller.

When you try to use `this` in a callback it has a different context

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('ProjectsController', function(Projects) {
    var vm = this;
    Projects.get().then(function(result) {
      vm.projectsData = result.data;
    });
  });
```